# Enterprise Library -- Unable to handle exception: 'LoggingExceptionHandler'

Tags: enterprise-library

I am trying to upgrade to Enterprise Library 5.0 and I'm getting this exception:

```
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionHandlingException occurred
  Message=Unable to handle exception: 'LoggingExceptionHandler'.
  Source=Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionPolicyEntry.ExecuteHandlerChain(Exception ex, Guid handlingInstanceID) in e:\Builds\EntLib\Latest\Source\Blocks\ExceptionHandling\Src\ExceptionHandling\ExceptionPolicyEntry.cs:line 148
       at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionPolicyEntry.Handle(Exception exceptionToHandle) in e:\Builds\EntLib\Latest\Source\Blocks\ExceptionHandling\Src\ExceptionHandling\ExceptionPolicyEntry.cs:line 87
       at KTBS.Common.ServiceHelpers.LogHelper.HandleException(Exception ex) in C:\Work\ktbs\src\KTBS.Services\KTBS.Common\ServiceHelpers\LogHelper.cs:line 238
  InnerException:
```

Is there any way to get more information about this?

Comment: Can you post the <exceptionHandling></exceptionHandling> section of your web.config and the code for KTBS.Common.ServiceHelpers.LogHelper.HandleException(Exception ex)?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the custom formatter for logging exception, try replacing it with the default formatter that comes with the version of EntLib that you're using (i.e 5.0). If that stops the reported exception then you know that the culprit is the custom formatter.

If the problem is indeed with the custom formatter then I'd suggest you to go to this link.

[The EventTopicExceptionFormatter WILL work with EntLib 4.1!](http://www.pmddirect.com/wp/?p=3)

This is specific to CAB (Composite Application Block) but the same fix can be used elsewhere too.

I am working on an application that is built over CAB and I used to get the same exception as you've mentioned. And it was being caused by the custom formatter that I was using (in fact which came with SCSF by default but was based on EntLib 3.1). Changing the number of parameters passed to the constructor of this custom formatter solved the problem.